# AWK Script is not recognizing keys

Tags: validation, parsing, awk

I am looking at data that has been formatted terribly- Who ever inputted the data was not very careful to be consistent with the order of the fields for each row.

I have created and found dictionaries of common and uncommon first names, last names, prefixes and suffixes and I am trying to loop through the data clarifying which record is of what type.

My code recognizes the names and will spit out if it is a last name, male name, female name, and initials. It gets stuck on the prefixes and suffixes-- seems to not even be reading the input files even though all input files were created the exact same way-- they are divided by pressing "enter" at the end of the line.

I have tried doing each piece of the code separately, and then it works, somehow when I put it together it fails.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
BEGIN{
print "Loading tables... " > "/dev/stderr";

while ((getline < "dist.all.last") > 0)
last[toupper($1)] = $2;
while ((getline < "dist.female.first") > 0)
female[toupper($1)] = $2;
while ((getline < "dist.male.first") > 0)
male[toupper($1)] = $2;
while((getline < "suffixes") > 0)
suffix[toupper($1)]= 0;
while((getline < "prefixmale") > 0)
prefixm[toupper($1)]=0;
while((getline < "prefixfemale") > 0)
prefixf[toupper($1)]=0;
while((getline < "prefixneutral") > 0)
prefixn[toupper($1)]=0;
print "DONE loading tables... " > "/dev/stderr";

FS = "|";  
}

function bestGuess(w, val, ans){
val = 0.0;
ans = w;

if (w in last){
val = last[w];
ans = "l";
}
if ((w in female) && (female[w] > val)){
val = female[w];
ans = "f";
}
if ((w in male) && (male[w] > val)){
val = male[w];
ans = "m";
}

if (length(w) == 1){
ans = "i";  # its an initial
}

if (w in suffixm){
ans = "s";
}

 if(w in prefixm){
ans = "mp"
 }
 if(w in prefixf){
ans = "fp"
}
if(w in prefixn){
ans = "np"
}
return ans;
}

{
numWords = split(toupper($8), words, /[^A-Za-z]+/);

if (numWords > 0)
key = bestGuess(words[1]);

for(i=2; i <= numWords; i++)
if (length(words[i]) > 0)
    key = key " " bestGuess(words[i]);

print key "|" $8;

}
```

Comment: Show the input, and how you would like the output to be.  Just looking at code and debug it, is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting som debugging code in the beginning of your program just to check if the arrays are well defined.  For instance, before the line:

```
numWords = split(toupper($8), words, /[^A-Za-z]+/);
```

you could insert:

```
for (w in prefixm) {
   print w,prefixm[w]
}
print
for (w in prefixf) {
   print w,prefixf[w]
}
print
for (w in prefixn) {
   print w,prefixf[w]
}
exit
```